# Python imports torch package just fine but pytest does not; ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, import, pytest

I am using conda with PyTorch installed. I have the following file `test.py`:

```py
import torch

def test_test():
    print(torch.Tensor([1,2]))

test_test()
```

Running `python test.py` works fine:

```shell
> python test.py
tensor([1., 2.])
```

but running it with `pytest` gives me an error:

```shell
> pytest test.py
(...)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`.
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pytest` was installed globally, not in the coda environment. Installing it with `conda install pytest` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you're importing/using a function that employs `torch` but the module in which it is defined does not import torch. At least that's what fixed the problem for me when making sure `pytest` is within the environment didn't work.